# Ubuntu Software Center Missing and cannot install?

Tags: software-center

My ubuntu was remove ubuntu software center because i want to reinstall again.but i used terminal...i cannot to install ubuntu software center..

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Why?

Comment: How was it removed?..

Comment: please add to your question the terminal output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: isn't the software center installed by default? where did it go?

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy software-center`.

Answer (score 3):

You can install synaptic:

[image: Install via the software center]

or via: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

and than install software-center from syanptic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes sometimes you get broken packages and then run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to fix them. Sometimes it removes important software. Take care what you do and then install it right back after you notice it missing.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Fixes some of it.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Will install Synaptic and then you can choose packages there easier than on the command line. I suggest it for newbies who want to see what packages are available to install.